# My function manipulating std::string's produces unexpected results

Tags: c++, string, winapi, stdstring

I'm trying to make a function that finds all instances of a substring and replaces it with a new string, but it doesn't appear to work. Here is the code:

```
#include <string>
#include <windows.h>
void ReplaceSubstr(std::string mainstring, std::string substring1, std::string substring2)
{
    while (1)
    {
    int pos1 = mainstring.find (substring1);
    if (pos1 == -1)
        {
        return;
        }
    mainstring.erase(pos1, substring1.size());
    mainstring.insert(pos1, substring2);
    MessageBox (NULL, "successfully ran", NULL, NULL);
    }
}

int main()
{
    std::string target = "this string needs fixing";
    std::string bereplaced = "needs fixing";
    std::string replacement = "is fixed";
    ReplaceSubstr (target, bereplaced, replacement);
    MessageBox (NULL, target.c_str(), NULL, NULL);
    return 0;
}
```

2 `MessageBox`s appear when the code is ran, first one with the text "successfully ran" and then another with the text "this string needs fixing". What I expected is for the second `MessageBox` to appear with the text "this string is fixed" instead.

Comment: This will hang if replacement is the same.

Comment: You're passing the string *by value*.

Comment: @Joachim Pileborg thanks, I can't believe I missed that. If you add that as an answer I'll accept it and upvote it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do it easily by:-

```
 index = target.find(bereplaced.c_str(), index);
 if (index == string::npos) 
     //return or do something else

 target.replace(index, replacement.size(), replacement);
```

Comment: While this does address one issue with the original source, it doesn't address the question that was asked. Besides, code-only answers aren't generally useful. As often is the case, it's not the *what*, but the *why* that matters so much.

Comment: Plus, you are using a [std::string::find](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/find) overload, that stops working, when the argument contains embedded NUL characters. For no obvious reason, since there are overloads that take a `std::string` (both by reference to const as well as by value), with an otherwise identical signature. If that wasn't enough, your call to `replace` passes the wrong argument for the second parameter. No idea, why this received an up-vote, or was picked as the accepted answer.

Answer (score 1):

There are two issues with the code as posted:

- Calling [std::string::erase](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/erase) invalidates all iterators, namely, `pos1` can no longer be used once the member function returns (see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28227538/1889329)).
- You are passing arguments by *value*, so any modifications are reflected in the local, temporary copy only.

The first issue is particularly nasty, because it often appears to work. However, it's still undefined behavior, and needs to be addressed (either by using a [std::string::erase](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/erase) overload, that returns a valid iterator, or by calling [std::string::replace](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/replace) instead).

The second issue can be solved in two ways as well, either by passing the first argument by reference, or by returning a new string object.

A solution might look like this:

```
std::string ReplaceSubstr( const std::string& input, const std::string& pattern,
                                                     const std::string& replacement ) {
    std::string output{ input };
    auto pos = output.find( pattern );
    while ( pos != std::string::npos ) {
        output.replace( pos, pattern.size(), replacement );
        pos = output.find( pattern );
    }
    return output;
}
```

If you want to perform the replacement in-place, simply change the return type to `void`, replace the first parameter to a reference to non-const, and use `input` for all occurrences of `output` (minus the final `return` statement).