# Does using the erase function in a string invalidate iterators

Tags: c++, string, iterator, erase, invalidation

I have the following code that takes a string and erases non alphabet characters

```
void removeNonAlpha(string& str){
    for (string::iterator it = str.begin(); it < str.end(); it++){
        if (!(isUpperCaseLetter(*it) || isLowerCaseLetter(*it) || str == ' '))  
            str.erase(it--);

    }
}
```

I showed this to my professor and he told me that doing this is risky because it may invalidate the iterator that I'm using. However, I thought that erase will only invalidate iterators after the point of the erase, and I made sure not to use any iterators after that point. 
So could this code crash or cause any undefined behavior?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`std::vector::erase` works as you suggest; it only invalidates iterators starting with the first erased element. However, that doesn't apply to `std::string`.

#### C++ allows string iterators to be invalidated at the drop of a hat.

The C++ standard has traditionally been more flexible with the requirements for `std::string`. (Or, in other words, it has traditionally allowed implementers to use optimizations which would not be valid for vectors.) And so it is with `std::string::erase`, and other string mutators.

In `[string.require]` (§21.4.1 of n3797), the standard accepts that:

6. References, pointers, and iterators referring to the elements of a `basic_string` sequence may be invalidated by the following uses of that `basic_string` object:

   - as an argument to any standard library function taking a reference to non-const `basic_string` as an argument.
   - Calling non-const member functions, except `operator[]`, `at`, `front`, `back`, `begin`, `rbegin`, `end`, and `rend`.

In other words, calling a potentially mutating function like `std::string::erase` could invalidate all iterators to that string, *even if no visible modifications are made to the string* (for example, because the range to be erased is empty).

(The latest draft C++ standard has the same wording, although it is now paragraph 4.)

#### The proposed code involves undefined behaviour if the first character of the string is not alphabetic.

In the first loop through the string, the iterator `it` has the value `str.begin()`. That iterator cannot be decremented, since the result would not be inside the string. And therefore, incrementing the decremented iterator might not return `it` to `str.begin()` for the next iteration.

#### Use indices rather than iterators

None of the above applies to integer position indices. So if you could safely replace your loop with the very similar:

```
void removeNonAlpha(string& str){
    for (auto sz = str.size(), i = 0; i < sz; ++i){
        if (!(isUpperCaseLetter(str[i]) ||
              isLowerCaseLetter(str[i]) ||
              str[i] == ' '))  
            str.erase(i--);
    }
}
```

Comment: You can use the return value from str.erase() to update the iterator with the iterator of the character that now occupies where the previous iterator was. I presume this would be a valid iterator and wouldn't require indices.

itr = --str.erase(itr);

Comment: @erroneous: correct in principle, but it won't work if you remove the only character in the string (because you cannot decrement the end iterator in that case). Also, the assignment to post-decrement is poor style imho.

Comment: then you can do itr = str.erase(itr); if(itr != str.end())--itr; (or remove itr++ from for loop and only increment on else).