# Removing starting characters from string using std::string::erase

Tags: c++, string, stl

I am trying to truncate beginning zeros from a string, so I used sequence erase function

`string& erase (size_t pos = 0, size_t len = npos);`

This is my implementaion:

```
    string str="000010557";
            for(char c:str){
            cout<<c<<" "<<str<<" "<<"\n";// for debug purpose
            if(c=='0')
                str.erase(0,1);
            else
                break;

        }
        cout<<str;
```

the output string that I got is `0010557` instead of`10557` and debug statements prints:

```
0 000010557 
0 00010557 
1 0010557
```

I read the documentation of [erase](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/erase/) and  [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28226836/does-using-the-erase-function-in-a-string-invalidate-iterators) post thinking might there be some iterator invalidation but implementing the code snippet recommended in the accepted answer also gave the same output, please help me understand where is the problem.

I am new to using stl library functions, so please forgive any negligence of mine,Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `for` loop is incrementing the position from which `c` is extracted, even if you erase a leading zero. Thus, after two runs of the loop, you have erased the *first* and *third* of the leading zeros, then the `c` value will be the first `1`.

Here's an attempt at following what happens in your code:

```
Start of first loop:
    "000010557"
     ^
     c is '0', so erase is called, making the string:
    "00010557"

At the end of this first loop, the position is incremented, so...

Start of second loop:
    "00010557"
      ^  (Note that we've skipped a zero!)
      c is '0', so erase is called, making the string:
    "0010557"

End of loop, position increment, and we skip another zero, so...

Start of third loop:
    "0010557"
       ^
       c is not '0', so we break out of the loop.
```

Instead, you should use a `while` loop, testing *only* the first character:

```cpp
int main()
{
    string str = "000010557";
    char c;
    while ((c = str.at(0)) == '0') {
       cout << c << " " << str << " " << "\n";// for debug purpose
       str.erase(0, 1);
    }
    cout << str;
}
```

Output:

```
0 000010557
0 00010557
0 0010557
0 010557
10557
```

Of course, you only need the `c` variable for your 'debugging' line so, without that, you can just have:

```cpp
int main()
{
    string str = "000010557";
    while (str.at(0) == '0') str.erase(0, 1);
    cout << str;
}
```

Comment: Ok, this is what I understood, this for loop behaves like position incrementation instead of character incrementation(what I thought during my implementation), after deletion of char c,position is increased but that position increment cause char increment by greater than 1. Am I on the right way? And is there a way to just iterate through the string alongside with erase,for example if I need to erase at random position but still move ahead for further erase.

Answer (score 1):

Even if you get this code to work, it's not a good solution. Removing a single character from the front of a string means moving all of the subsequent characters down one position, and the code does that for every leading zero. Instead, count the leading zeros and remove them all at once:

```
std::string::size_type non_zero_pos = 0;
while (non_zero_pos < str.size() && str[non_zero_pos] == '0')
    ++non_zero_pos;
str.erase(0, non_zero_pos);
```

That way, the (expensive) erase operation is only done once.

Or use iterators:

```
auto non_zero_it = std::find_first_not_of(std::begin(str), std::end(str), "0");
str.erase(std::begin(str), non_zero_it);
```

Edit: fixed search for non-0 iterator.